# Coloring the excel output in Sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, colors, scikit-learn

I want to conditional format each row of my exported output data-frame(Output format: excel file)based on a single column(max_probabilities column in my data-frame).
If probability in the max_probabilities is greater than 0.75 I want that particular entire row to be colored Green else it has to be colored Red.
How do i do it.(Note: I want to color my exported excel rows not the dataframe)
Dataframe format Code:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Details':x_test,'Amount':test_data.xn_Amount,'Category':Classified_Category,'Probability':max_probabilities})
```

This is how my exported dataframe looks like as of now.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [conditional formats](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html) but it coloring only column:

```
import string

df = pd.DataFrame({'Amount':[1,2,3],
                   'max_probabilities':[.1,2,.3]})
print (df)
   Amount  max_probabilities
0       1                0.1
1       2                2.0
2       3                0.3
```

---

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_conditional.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
red_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color':'red'})
green_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color':'green'})

#dict for map excel header, first A is index, so omit it
d = dict(zip(range(25), list(string.ascii_uppercase)[1:]))
#print (d)

col = 'max_probabilities'
excel_header = str(d[df.columns.get_loc(col)])
#get length of df
len_df = str(len(df.index) + 1)
rng = excel_header + '2:' + excel_header + len_df
print (rng)
C2:C4

worksheet.conditional_format(rng, {'type': 'cell',
                                      'criteria': '<',
                                       'value':     0.75,
                                       'format': red_format})

worksheet.conditional_format(rng, {'type': 'cell',
                                      'criteria': '>=',
                                       'value':   0.75,
                                       'format':  green_format})
writer.save()
```

If want coloring rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Amount':[1,2,3],
                   'Category':['a','d','f'],
                   'max_probabilities':[.1,2,.3]})
print (df)
   Amount Category  max_probabilities
0       1        a                0.1
1       2        d                2.0
2       3        f                0.3

def highlight(x):
    c1 = 'background-color: green'
    c2 = 'background-color: red' 
    #if want set no default colors 
    #c2 = ''  
    m = x['max_probabilities'] > .75
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(c2, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    df1.loc[m, :] = c1
    return df1

df.style.apply(highlight, axis=None).to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @jezrael  can I know how to color the entire row.

Comment: @PoorneshV - Check second solution, for row first does not work because test each cell.